# Postman - local request

Tags: proxy, request, postman

Why does Postman go through proxy when I make a local request (@127.0.0.1:8080 for example)?

Is it possible to change this behavior?

Since I have a username&password proxy, I can't set it up properly in Postman and the solution of creating a .bat file with `set https_proxy`, `set http_proxy` etc. did not work for me:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=''
set HTTPS_PROXY=''
set http_proxy=''
set https_proxy=''
start C:\path\to\Postman.exe
```

Solution is described [here](https://support.getpostman.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008893713-How-do-I-configure-Postman-to-work-through-a-proxy-).

Comment: So what is your question? Why postman makes a local request through a proxy and whether it is possible to change that? But why then have you added a solution link to your answer and not in your answer section? And yes, please don't post link solutions only. Please also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers in case you want to answer with this link

Comment: @qant My question is twofold: First, yes, why is it making local requests through proxy?(this is just for my understanding of the matter). Second, is it possible to change this? If the answer is yes, then how? If the answer is no, then what is a possible workaround since the solution from the link hasn't worked for me.